# iframe scrollHeight in Chrome 5 version

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to get Iframe scrolling height by using document.getElementById('frame_name').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight; but this code not working till document.getElementById('frame_name').contentWindow i am able to get Object but after that am getting 'undefined' error for trying to access iframe document like document.getElementById('frame_name').contentWindow.document

Comment: Check this link. It might give you what you're searching. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/iframessi2.htm

Comment: given link code not working for Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

If you're building this for a Chrome plugin, there's currently a bug with frames/iframes.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20773.

From the bug report:

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

Try to access window.frames[some_index] from a content script

**What is the expected result?**

We get the frame

**What happens instead?**

For all n, window.frames[n] = undefined